# Evaluating True and False in a python list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
answers = [True, False, True, False]
formatted_answer = ["yes" if True else "no" for answer in answers]
print(formatted_answer)
```

```
['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes']
```

Why does this statement seem to evaluate False as True but if I reword it:

```
formatted_answer = ["yes" if answer else "no" for answer in answers]
```

I get the correct result?

Answer (score 0):

Python evaluates expressions in the list comprehension. The condition is then tested for "truthiness" by taking its boolean value. To highlight, we could add parenthesis to highlight each.

```
[("yes") if bool(True) else ("no") for answer in iter(answers)]
```

`True` is an expression that is always `True`.

In the second case,

```
[("yes") if bool(answer) else ("no") for answer in iter(answers)]
```

Now you'll get "yes" or "no" depending on whether `answer` holds a truthy value.

Answer (score 0):

True is always true. Therefore the condition in your list comprehension can only ever add 'yes' to your list.

When True and False are used in an arithmetic context they evaluate to 1 and 0 respectively. This fact leads to an amusing list comprehension for your data:

```
answers = [True, False, True, False]
formatted_answer = [['no', 'yes'][e] for e in answers]
print(formatted_answer)
```

**Output:**

```
['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no']
```

Answer (score -2):

I didn't get your question what are you trying to ask.
But in this
`formatted_answer = ["yes" if True else "no" for answer in answers]`
if condition is always True it is not evaluating answer you provided it a True boolean value.

than in later case it is evaluating answer "if answer"

I hope you were asking same.